# jquery datepicker does not load in MVC4

Tags: jquery

In my layout i have referenced the following files:

```
 <link type="text/css" href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in my index.cshtml i have added following line inside `<script>` tag

```
$("#Start_Date").datepicker();
```

my input of type text:

```
<input type="text" name="Start_Date" id="Start_Date" />
```

But it is showing error:

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

I have checked all files but can't find any error.
Any clue will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try using a more recent version of `jQuery-ui`

Comment: can you post some more code like how do you initialize the datepicker? You might need to initialize the datepicker like:$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../Content/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            //alert("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
            RetrieveCalendar();
        }
    });

Comment: Why have you commented original `jquery-ui.js` file and included `customer.min.js`?

Comment: @user2611292, to code to initialise datepicker is already there.

Comment: Why is this minus voted??? i have done work with jquery datepicker earlier as well. But Here i became surprised why my datepicker is not working!!!!!!!!!, Hence none of the answers have worked. And Also i tried in all the ways earlier as well

Comment: i tried with that also  Shaunak D

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added `jQuery` twice. Use updated one.

There could be several Reasons:

1. The jquery.ui is used before jquery.
2. The $ is used by another library.

Comment: surprisingly it shows TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function while loading the dom.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to initialize the datepicker like :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../Content/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            //alert("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
            RetrieveCalendar();
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 form-control" placeholder="Select Date" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<link type="text/css" href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(function() {
    $("#Start_Date").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Finally i got the solution, It was actually due to MVC4 purpose:

I commented out the following files from _layout.cshtml:

```
   @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@
```

And then added my desired files in the head section of the _layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And then in index view the error went way.

```
$(function() {
    $("#Start_Date").datepicker();
});
```

Also the above code snippet worked fine :)

Browse to the link given below to get the knowledge about bundles regarding this in MVC4:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/jquery-ui-datepicker-in-mvc-4-issue/